# PHP MySQL query with variable

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query:

```
$result = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE partner = '$pName'");
```

Can you help my to write the query right?

Comment: Do you get an error? The SQL itself look correct.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When I write:  $result = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE partner =?")->execute('name'); I'll get an output but I want a variable not a simple value.

Comment: The output should be just a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
$result = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE partner = '".$pName."'");
```

Comment: Its was my mistake, the variable was clean, there where styles in it. -.-